# Create User Defined Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure that allows me to input the name of a table as the in variable (tblname) and then perform some operations on that table. The columns callingparty and callduration that I reference in the function are preexisting columns of any tables that will be used. I am new to creating procedures and every time I fix an error another one pops up.

**Currently I am receiving the error:**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'concat(short, tblname); create temporary table temp (index callingparty (calling' at line 8
```

and I'm not sure how to fix this one or what is wrong with my syntax. Is it just that it isn't possible to create a new table that includes the name of the old table?

```
drop procedure if exists shortcallcount;

delimiter $$
create procedure shortcallcount(`tblname` varchar(32))

begin
drop table if exists temp;
drop table if exists temp2;
drop table if exists temp3;
drop table if exists join1;
drop table if exists concat(short, tblname);
create temporary table temp (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select callingparty, count(*) as totalcount from tblname group by callingparty;
create temporary table temp2 (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select callingparty, count(*) as tencount from tblname where callduration<1000 group by callingparty;
create temporary table temp3 (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select callingparty, count(*) as fourcount from tblname where callduration<492 group by callingparty;

create temporary table join1 (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select temp.callingparty, ifnull(temp3.fourcount, 0) as fourcount, temp.totalcount from temp left outer join temp3 on temp.callingparty=temp3.callingparty;
create table concat(short, tblname) (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select join1.callingparty, join1.fourcount; ifnull(temp2.tencount, 0) as tencount, join1.totalcount from join1 left outer join temp2 on join1.callingparty=temp2.callingparty;
drop table temp;
drop table temp2;
drop table temp3;
drop table join1;
end$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you have to use prepared statements. Search for "mysql dynamic table name", you have a lot of answers already.

Comment: @rlanvin Okay, I'll look into that! Thanks

Comment: One thing that comes to my sight is that `concat` is a reserved word in mysql so either you change it or use backticks around it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm trying to use the concatenate function here. The idea would be if for example my original table was named extable, that line would create a table called shortextable. I'm not sure if that's possible I guess, but I'm trying to use "concat" as a command rather than part of the name

Comment: Then you have to do as @rlanvin mentioned. You need to use dynamic code to create such table. You can not use a function to define a table name.

Answer (score 0):

You may use prepared statements, because the variable names doesn't evaluate on table names or column names.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure shortcallcount(tblname varchar(32))
begin
    drop table if exists temp;
    drop table if exists temp2;
    drop table if exists temp3;
    drop table if exists join1;
    -- drop table if exists concat(short, tblname);
    set @sql = concat("drop table if exists short", tblname,";");
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

    create temporary table temp (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select callingparty, count(*) as totalcount from tblname group by callingparty;
    create temporary table temp2 (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select callingparty, count(*) as tencount from tblname where callduration<1000 group by callingparty;
    create temporary table temp3 (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select callingparty, count(*) as fourcount from tblname where callduration<492 group by callingparty;

    create temporary table join1 (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select temp.callingparty, ifnull(temp3.fourcount, 0) as fourcount, temp.totalcount from temp left outer join temp3 on temp.callingparty=temp3.callingparty;
    -- create table concat(short, tblname) (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select join1.callingparty, join1.fourcount; ifnull(temp2.tencount, 0) as tencount, join1.totalcount from join1 left outer join temp2 on join1.callingparty=temp2.callingparty;
    set @sql = concat("create table short",tblname," (index callingparty (callingparty)) as select join1.callingparty, join1.fourcount; ifnull(temp2.tencount, 0) as tencount, join1.totalcount from join1 left outer join temp2 on join1.callingparty=temp2.callingparty;");
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

    drop table temp;
    drop table temp2;
    drop table temp3;
    drop table join1;
end$$

delimiter ;
```